# avoid duplicate xml data from sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to convert xml value into table using sql server.

From this xml value and the sql query,

```
<ROOT>
    <NODE1>
        <VALUE>NODE1_VALUE1</VALUE>
    </NODE1>
    <NODE1>
        <VALUE>NODE1_VALUE2</VALUE>
        <NODE2>
            <VALUE>NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1</VALUE>
        </NODE2>
        <NODE2>
            <VALUE>NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2</VALUE>
        </NODE2>
    </NODE1>
</ROOT>


SELECT NODE1.C.VALUE('VALUE[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') NODE1_VALUE
    ,NODE2.C.VALUE('VALUE[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') NODE2_VALUE
FROM TABLENAME T
CROSS APPLY T.TEXT.NODES('/ROOT/NODE1') NODE1(C)
CROSS APPLY T.TEXT.NODES('/ROOT/NODE1/NODE2') NODE2(C)
```

I am getting this result, But NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1 is not the child of NODE1_VALUE1.

```
NODE1_VALUE     NODE2_VALUE
==================================
NODE1_VALUE1    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1
NODE1_VALUE1    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2
```

But I need the following result. How can I change the sql query to get this result?

```
NODE1_VALUE     NODE2_VALUE
==================================
NODE1_VALUE1    NULL
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2

(OR)

NODE1_VALUE     NODE2_VALUE
==================================
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1
NODE1_VALUE2    NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2
```

Comment: Rather than cross applying the table for NODE2(C), outer apply to the first node. e.g. `FROM TABLENAME T CROSS APPLY T.TEXT.nodes('ROOT/NODE1') NODE1(C) OUTER APPLY NODE1.C.nodes('NODE2') NODE2(C)`. NOTE: a cross apply will achieve the second result, an outer apply the first.

Comment: Thank you ZLK it worked correctly. Also I noticed that 'nodes' and 'value' must be in lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x XML = N'
<ROOT>
    <NODE1>
        <VALUE>NODE1_VALUE1</VALUE>
    </NODE1>
    <NODE1>
        <VALUE>NODE1_VALUE2</VALUE>
        <NODE2>
            <VALUE>NODE1_NODE2_VALUE1</VALUE>
        </NODE2>
        <NODE2>
            <VALUE>NODE1_NODE2_VALUE2</VALUE>
        </NODE2>
    </NODE1>
</ROOT>'

SELECT t.c.value('(VALUE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
     , t2.c2.value('(VALUE/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @x.nodes('//NODE1') t (c)
OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('NODE2') t2 (c2)
```